# How to concatenate two columns based on another column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
A   B       C           Result(A)   |Result(B)
1   All     9                    1  |     All~9-8
1   All     8                    2  |     Been~6
2   Been    6                    3  |     Hai~5
3   Hai     5               
2   Been    6
```

A,B and C are column names B and C should be concatenated based on column a and should be stored in two columns Result(A) and Result(B)

Comment: You need to describe this in more detail as it is not clear what you want.

Comment: Try to add some more description about question and explain your requirement so that people can help you

Comment: the logic/rules as to how/why the results you've shown come about need to be explained, because it's not at all obvious how they should be derived.

Comment: A,B and C are column names and Result(A) and (b) are the result column names from column names @SimonWoolf

Answer (score 0):

A result not exacly the same as in your sample but similar could be based on CONCAT_WS

```
    select a, b, concat(b,'~', concat_ws('-',c))
    from my_table 
    group by A,B
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `group_concat` for this

```
SELECT A AS Result_A, CONCAT(B,'~', GROUP_CONCAT(C SEPARATOR '~')) AS Result_B FROM table  GROUP BY B
```

Ref: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php